# React importing javascript module issue on run time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, adminlte

I want to call $.AdminLTE from my tsx file, here's what I've done:

```
declare var $: JQueryStatic & {
   AdminLTE: any;
}

componentDidMount() {
   $.AdminLTE.layout.fix()
}
```

And also added the library file inside my index.html with the following orders:

```
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/app.min.js"></script> <!-- AdminLTE file -->
<script src="dist/app.js"></script>
```

But, it still output the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'layout' of undefined

P.S: When I tried in Chrome's console in developer tools, it works fine and not undefined.

Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: So `$.AdminLTE` is in a file called `assets/js/app.min.js`? Just checking since that is very surprising.

Comment: @aluan-haddad No, it's in dist/app.js (bundled file).

Comment: So I assume you are using a module bundler and need to import whatever defines it with `import "path/to/module/that/adds/adminLTE/tojquery`" in order to ensure load order is correct. Just a guess. Need to see more of the consuming file. This relates to how you consume jQuery as well.

Comment: @aluan-haddad Yes, I used webpack to bundle all of my scripts (dist/app.js), and AdminLTE is a standalone javascript file (app.min.js). But, in my script when I called $.AdminLTE, it's undefined.

Comment: I see. Can you post the whole script or module containing `componentDidMount`? Does it import anything? If it is a module, your declaration is incorrect.

Comment: @aluan-haddad Of course, here: https://pastebin.com/zWWHzDjj

Comment: One thing to note, although not the cause, is that you need to write `declare global { interface JQueryStatic { AdminLTE; } }` since you are declaring an augmentation to the global scope from within a module. More significantly, if anything in your primary bundle uses jQuery, then a different instance of `$`, one which is not augmented by the file containing adminLTE, may be being provided to your app bundle unless Webpack is aware that jQuery and bootstrap and adminLTE are all loaded from external sources as globals.

Comment: @aluan-haddad I see, I will declare it as `global`.

Comment: That will be good since what you currently have is declaring a variable that is scoped to the module **Dashboard.tsx**.

Comment: @aluan-haddad I'm sure that both of `jQuery` and `AdminLTE` modules have been provided before my own bundled scripts. But, still curious why it was returned `undefined`.

Comment: so Webpack has an external declared with the name `$`? or maybe with some provide plugin or something? Nevermind, I guess you are just using a global `$`. It is better to do all of this through your loader or packager (i.e. with Webpack)

Comment: @aluan-haddad I declared `window.$ = window.jQuery = $;` in my `vendor.js` file and not included in Webpack bundle. Here is my whole `index.html` script: https://pastebin.com/xFPBgBSa

Comment: And what does vendor.js look like?

Comment: @aluan-haddad Like this https://pastebin.com/6H78X68S

Comment: @aluan-haddad And `AdminLTE's app.js` looks like https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/dist/js/app.js

Comment: That looks like a timing bug. None of that code should be in vendor.js. vendor files generally list imports, as opposed to bootstrapping code. Move all the logic in vendor.js to a point _after_ all scripts have loaded.

Comment: @aluan-haddad The code in `vendor.js` works fine, only `Dashboard.tsx` which get into the trouble.

Comment: @aluan-haddad I fixed it by using javascript `setInterval` to wait until `$.AdminLTE` is loaded and call `$.AdminLTE.layout.fix()` when it's fully loaded. It works fine now.

Comment: Glad it works! That is an awful hack though. There is a timing bug that needs fixing. Different environments may take longer to load the script.